# c++ multithreaded server with std::thread casting variables

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets

im just started coding in c++ and i am trying to build a multithreaded server but i got some errors. first, here is the code i got:

```
while(true){
        printf("waiting for a connection\n");
        csock = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));

        if((*csock = accept( hsock, (sockaddr*)&sadr, &addr_size))!= -1)
        {
            printf("---------------------\nReceived connection from   %s\n",inet_ntoa(sadr.sin_addr));
            //std::thread th(&Network::SocketHandler, NULL);

            std::thread th(Network::SocketHandler, (void*)csock);
            th.detach();
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error accepting %d\n", errno);
        }
    }

    }


    void Network::SocketHandler(void* lp)
    {
        int *csock = (int*)lp;

       char buffer[1024];
       int buffer_len = 1024;
       int bytecount;

       memset(buffer, 0, buffer_len);
       if((bytecount = recv(*csock, buffer, buffer_len, 0))== -1){
          fprintf(stderr, "Error receiving data %d\n", errno);

       }
       printf("Received bytes %d\nReceived string \"%s\"\n", bytecount, buffer);
       strcat(buffer, " SERVER ECHO");

       if((bytecount = send(*csock, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0))== -1){
          fprintf(stderr, "Error sending data %d\n", errno);

       }

       printf("Sent bytes %d\n", bytecount);

    }
```

i am getting a error when compiling at this line:

```
std::thread th(Network::SocketHandler, (void*)csock);
```

saying: 
std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (Network::*)(int*); _Args = {void*}]
no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘’ to ‘void (Network::*&&)(int*)’

how can i fix this? or is there a better way to create a multithreaded server any examples maybe of other posts?

Comment: You might consider looking at Boost.Asio for a c++ networking library

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why are you passing in a `void *` instead of an `int *` when it's clear that what you really want is an `int *`?

Just change the function signature to:

```
void Network::SocketHandler(int* csock)
```

and remove the cast in the code that does the calling:

```
std::thread th(Network::SocketHandler, csock);
```

Now, you will still get an error, and it will be for a different reason. `Network::SocketHandler` is a member function. It needs a `this` pointer. Normally you would call such functions with syntax like `object.SocketHandler(csock)` or `objptr->SocketHandler(csock)`. When you call it that way with `::std::thread` you aren't giving it an object to be called on. It has no `this` pointer.

What you should do is change the function signature again to:

```
static void Network::SocketHandler(int* csock)
```

and then your code will work just fine. It doesn't look like the function makes use of any member variables, so it doesn't need a `this` pointer.

On a different note, it looks like you're trying to adapt something originally written for pthreads. If I were doing this for the C++11 thread library I would do it in a rather different manner.

I can't see your entire program, so I don't really have the luxury of re-designing it. But, from what I can see, I would make these tweaks:

```
while(true){
        printf("waiting for a connection\n");
        int csock = -1;

        if((csock = accept( hsock, (sockaddr*)&sadr, &addr_size))!= -1)
        {
            printf("---------------------\nReceived connection from   %s\n",inet_ntoa(sadr.sin_addr));
            //std::thread th(&Network::SocketHandler, NULL);

            std::thread th(Network::SocketHandler, csock);
            th.detach();
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error accepting %d\n", errno);
        }
    }

    }


    void Network::SocketHandler(int csock)
    {
       char buffer[1024];
       int buffer_len = 1024;
       int bytecount;

       memset(buffer, 0, buffer_len);
       if((bytecount = recv(csock, buffer, buffer_len, 0))== -1){
          fprintf(stderr, "Error receiving data %d\n", errno);

       }
       printf("Received bytes %d\nReceived string \"%s\"\n", bytecount, buffer);
       strcat(buffer, " SERVER ECHO");

       if((bytecount = send(csock, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0))== -1){
          fprintf(stderr, "Error sending data %d\n", errno);

       }

       printf("Sent bytes %d\n", bytecount);

    }
```

The changes are fairly subtle. The C++11 thread library lets you call functions and provide all their arguments, and it handles this in a thread-safe way. There is no need to pass `void *` anymore, nor is there a need to use `malloc` or `new` to create storage space for those arguments you can just pass the arguments your thread needs directly to the thread constructor.

Your program, in fact, has a memory leak. It never reclaims the space it `malloc`s for `csock` to point to. If it ran for a long time, it would eventually run out of memory as the space for all those filehandles was never reclaimed.

Your program may also have a filehandle leak. You do not appear to `close` the socket in `Network::SocketHandler`. But since I don't have visibility on your entire program, I can't be sure about that.

Comment: what manner is better according to you? this was originally written for pthreads but some people told me that c++11 thread was better.

Comment: @user1971401: I'll write up something for you later. It's not that big of a change actually. BTW, they're right, C++11 threads are better to use for a variety of reasons.

Comment: @user1971401: There, I changed your program as much as I could given the knowledge I have about it and explained my reasoning.